# event is triggered several times (sales_order_save_commit_after)

Tags: magento

Could you please tell me why sales_order_save_commit_after is triggered twice when order is completed?
I moved all logic to sales_order_save_before, but I use sales_order_save_commit_after to make sure that it's called only once. I want to make sure that there are no superflous writing to database. I tried to use debugger to understand how it works, but I haven't understood so far, it seems rather complicated.
I  see 2 callbacks but I can't understand why is there 2 callbacks for model order.
Does magento write to database several times that triggers sales_order_save_commit_after multiple times?

Comment: I saw this post http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7730/sales-order-save-commit-after-event-triggered-twice, but I didn't find answer there.

Answer (score 1):

If an order contains configurable products, the collection returned by `$order->getAllItems();` will contain parent and child products resulting in double element count for this product type. It is safer to use `$order->getAllVisibleItems()`